# Can't display data in View

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am new to the Java Spring MVC thing. Following some tutorials on web, I don't know why but when I pass some text to the `view` from the `controller`, the text don't seem to appear.

`Controller`

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
        String message = "Hello Spring MVC!";
        return new ModelAndView("helloWorld", "message", message);
    }
}
```

`View`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Message is: ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

All of that tutorials I am following have this exact code, but it just won't work. What do I miss here?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done JSP, but I'm pretty sure that is not how you declare a String in JSP. `Message is: ${message}` is interpreted as literal text, no?

Comment: It isn't interpreted at all, can't see the text.

Answer (score 0):

If showing the message is all you need, try adding `HttpServletRequest` to the parameters received by `helloWorld`:

```
public ModelAndView helloWorld(HttpServletRequest request){
```

Then use `setAttribute` to show the message:

```
request.setAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC!");
```

Edit: And turns out this edict was no needed

I did forget that in the jsp you need something like:

```
<p><c:out value="${message}" /></p>
```

And this in the top of the page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. What's the deal with my code above? Why it won't work, and in every single tutorial it is showed like that?

Comment: My bad, I glanced back to my jsp and saw I missed some information, thought the code would not work.

Anyway, I'm not expert in Spring but when I've found myself having this issues it usually means I've missed to set the  `path` property in the the forms that will use the data in the .`jsp`

Comment: Thank you for the help anyway. I will try to experiment with the code you gave me, I guess I will understand it better.

Comment: Above answer does not leverage model attribute concept of spring. You are doing old school way of setting in request scope and using it in JSP. Do you have bean declared similar to the one below in your mvc servlet-xml? <bean id="viewResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >

Comment: Yes, I have that `bean` in the `servlet`.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine. Just to be sure, you are creating a JSP file for helloWorld.htm right?

I simply put your code into helloWorld.jsp and it works fine.

```js
package com.dhargis.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {


     @RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
         String message = "Hello Spring MVC!";
         return new ModelAndView("helloWorld", "message", message);
     }
 
 
 
}

-------------------------------------JSP----------------------------------------------------


helloWorld.jsp

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Message is: ${message}
    </body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

I then removed the <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> and it still works fine.

Send me a follow up question or I can put it on Github for you.

Comment: Yes, `helloWorld` is `JSP` file. I don't understand why it won't work for me.

Comment: If you can, put the whole project on `Github` so I can check if it will work.

Comment: I have looked into the project on `Github`, but it is exactly what I have done too. And still, won't work. Can't find out these days what is wrong, have read a bunch of tutorials and still won't work.

Comment: Maybe there is a step you're missing. Lets create a template project and then add your controller:
1) So if you are using STS Version: 3.6.3.SR1 with Pivital Tc as your server.
2) New -> Spring Project -> Spring MVC Project
3) Give it a minute for Maven to resolve your dependencies. 
4) Right click on the Pivital tc server and click Add/Remove and add the project.
5) Right Click on the project->Properties->Web Project Settings->Context root. example:MVC
6) Right click on the Pivital tc Server and click clean
7) Right click on the Pivital tc Server and start
8) check to see localhost:8080/MVC